# Problems with htaccess Redirect (Page on one domain to same page on another)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a few pages to a new domain and I have done this before but for some reason I can't get the code to work.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 http://domain.com/page1.html http://domain2.com/page1.html
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you only want to direct a FEW of your pages and not all of them, you can do:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /~myaccount/oldpage.html http://www.newsite.com/newpage.html
```

You specify the path to the page on your current server followed by the URL to redirect to.

OR you can do:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldpage\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/newpage.html
```

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess file the below code will ensure that all your directories and pages of your old domain will get correctly redirected to your new domain.

The .htaccess file needs to be placed in the root directory of your old website

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hint: You can use 4 spaces at the begining of a line to make it a code block and 2 spaces at any place but code blocks breaks the line. I've already edited your answer to fix this.

Comment: He says he wants to direct A FEW of his pages, not all.

Comment: Yeah I don't need all of them to redirect just 6 of them.    Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.