# redirect all old “.html” extensions to new “/”

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have recently moved my old website to new domain. Now I want to redirect all old website URL to new website URLs.

Here is an example exactly what I want to do:

www.oldsite.com/old-page-number.html (This is old website page)

www.newsite.com/old-page-number/ (This is new website page)

Similarly I want to redirect all of my old pages to new domain website pages.

Can you please suggest how do I do it using .htaccess file.

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: May b this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235877/problems-with-htaccess-redirect-page-on-one-domain-to-same-page-on-another

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/$1/ [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply!

The given code is working for all "post" sections.

But it is not redirecting for the following section of WordPress CMS:

Example:

www.oldsite.com/tag/tagging-page

www.oldsite.com/category/category-page

Also

If any one of pages are broken in www.oldsite.com, it should redirect to new website domain (www.newsite.com).

Can you please suggest the code for it.

Comment: I'm using the following current codes:

RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/newsite\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

The above code does redirect all oldsite.com to newsite.com with "Wild Card Redirect".

but the oldsite.com has post URLs ending with .html, so i don't want this to in newsite.com as stated with my question.

Comment: Clearly you're not using the answer suggested by me so how do you think it will work for you?

Comment: I've already tried the code:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ http://www.newsite.com/$1/ [L,R=301,NC,NE]

but as i stated first it is not working for tags and category pages.

Comment: Rather than saying ` it is not working for tags and category pages` you need to provide exact URL for which it doesn't work.